# I am unable to claim cStor volume using the custom cStor storage pool

Tags: openebs

I was creating manual Cstor pool for disks attached to my nodes, but i am unable to claim volume using the custom storage pool
cStor storage pools are running in healthy state.

```
gem-cstor-disk-9wzj-6c9c8f75c5-mq6gp                              2/2     Running   0          154m
gem-cstor-disk-iru2-68c85445cf-pqg6b                              2/2     Running   0          132m
gem-cstor-disk-m3bx-6fcddc7dcd-f9dg2                              2/2     Running   0          154m
```

From maya-apiserver,

```
2019/01/16 12:47:17.907038 [ERR] http: Request GET /latest/volumes/pvc-b8dacfcc-198c-11e9-9141-503eaa028845, error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context
2019/01/16 12:47:17.907070 [DEBUG] http: Request /latest/volumes/pvc-b8dacfcc-198c-11e9-9141-503eaa028845 (596.053376ms)
2019/01/16 12:47:43.536149 [DEBUG] http: Request /latest/volumes/pvc-b9a40023-198c-11e9-9141-503eaa028845 (GET)
I0116 12:47:43.536184       8 volume_endpoint_v1alpha1.go:52] cas template based volume request was received: method 'GET'
I0116 12:47:43.536206       8 volume_endpoint_v1alpha1.go:137] cas template based volume read request was received
E0116 12:47:44.705380       8 volume_endpoint_v1alpha1.go:175] failed to read cas template based volume: error 'error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context'
2019/01/16 12:47:44.705424 [ERR] http: Request GET /latest/volumes/pvc-b9a40023-198c-11e9-9141-503eaa028845, error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: mapping values are not allowed in this context
2019/01/16 12:47:44.705458 [DEBUG] http: Request /latest/volumes/pvc-b9a40023-198c-11e9-9141-503eaa028845 (1.169318391s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Going thourgh PVC, SC yamls and found that StorageClass YAML is not correct. It contain extra space added. Just removed and re-applied. Everything went fine.